# What is mage in magento ,,explain following and also list all these kind of function or model used in magento

Tags: product, category, magento-1, model

And also explain following function:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
load();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Mage` is a super-class used to obtain access to the main methods/processes used in Magento.

`Mage::getModel('catalog/product');` returns new (empty) instance of the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class.

`load()` - the regular method of `AbstractModel` in Magento which loads corresponding model's data from the database.

`$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');` - get new category model and store it in the `$category` variable. Later you can add a data to it and save it using `save()`.

`$category->load($categoryid);` - loads from the databse specific category in case when the `$category` is instance of `AbstractModel`.

`$collection = $category->getProductCollection();` - returns the collection of a products for this category. Each of them is instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`.

`$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');` - select all of the available attributes during future load process. In case when the collection was already loaded will give no effect.